# Each item of a listView playing a different (short) media file. After so many clips I hear no more sound

Tags: java, android, listview, audio

I am making a sound board app. I have a String List of sound descriptions that populate the listView. My onItemClick takes in a switch statement that assigns each sound to it's string description from the list. The sounds work when the list item is clicked, but after so many clicks, all the sounds stop. the switch statement looks like this in my ItemOnClick:

```
switch (soundName){
    case "magic whoosh":
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.magic_whoosh);
        mediaPlayer.start();
        break;
   case "magic poof":
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.magic_poof);
        mediaPlayer.start();
        break;
}
```

Comment: Do you properly stop the current mediaPlayer before starting the next.

Comment: I tried adding a media Player.stop() at the end of each case but then the sound wouldn't play at all.

Comment: mediaplayer.stop() and then call mediaplayer.reset() Then you can use the same mediaplayer object to play a different file using setDataSource()

Comment: So include that coding in each case?  I'll try that out tonight. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As requested a possible answer;

```
//declare instance variable
static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

//handle listview on item click
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                   if(mediaPlayer==null){
                      mediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();
                      try{
                         mediaPlayer.setDataSource(//datasource based on position);
                         mediaPlayer.prepare(); //this uses  the same UI thread
                         mediaPlayer.start();
                      }catch(Throwable e){
                         //handle possible errors
                      }
                   }else{
                      if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())mediaPlayer.stop();
                      mediaPlayer.reset();
                      try{
                         mediaPlayer.setDataSource(//datasource based on position);
                         mediaPlayer.prepare(); //this uses  the same UI thread
                         mediaPlayer.start();
                      }catch(Throwable e){
                         //handle possible errors
                      }
                   }   
                }
});
```